# line integral - pararametrizations of sphere-plane intersection

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I need to calculate the following integral: $$\int_{\gamma}x^{2}ds $$ where $\gamma$ is defined by: \begin{cases}
 x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=a^{2} \\ 
 x+y+z=0
\end{cases}
$a>0$
I tried to use the fact that $2x^{2}+2xy=2(x+\frac{y}{2})^{2}-\frac{y^{2}}{2}$ then I used the notation $p=x+\frac{y}{2}$ and $q=y$

From my plane equation I got $z=-(x+y)$ then I replaced in the first one and I got $2x^{2}+2xy+2y^{2}=a^{2}$ .I replaced in this equation my notations and I got $2(p-\frac{q}{2})^{2}+2(p-\frac{q}{2})q+2q^{2}=a^{2}$

How to continue such that to obtain the parametrizations of the curve?

Comment: We know that $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+xz+yz)$, therefore in our case $-2(xy+yz+xz)=a^2$. Can this be useful?

Comment: the equation is $(2y+x)^2+3x^2=2a^2$ so a good parametrization is $x\sqrt 3=a\sqrt 2 \cos t, 2y+x=...$ and the integral is just $c(a)\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2t dt$ with $c(a)$ easy to compute (constant times $a^3$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice solution that doesn't use any integration or parametrization. Given the fact that there is a symmetry with the sphere and the plane $x+y+z=0$ we have that

$$\int_\gamma x^2ds = \int_\gamma y^2ds = \int_\gamma z^2ds$$

Thus the integral is simply

$$\int_\gamma x^2ds = \frac{1}{3}\int_\gamma (x^2+y^2+z^2)ds = \frac{1}{3}\int_\gamma a^2 ds = \frac{1}{3} a^2 L(\gamma)$$

Thinking carefully, the plane goes through the center of the sphere, therefore its intersection with the sphere will be a great circle (a circle with same radius as the sphere). This means our final result simplifies to

$$\int_\gamma x^2ds = \frac{1}{3} a^2 (2\pi a) = \frac{2}{3}\pi a^3$$